# Filtering rows out of a dataset. Size error

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows from the all_trips dataset that contain values from 2 different columns.  I need to remove rows that have "HR QR" in the start_station_name column, and rows that have negative values in the trip_length column.  I am attempting to create a new dataset(all_trips2) from the filtered data.

My code:

```r
all_trips2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name=="HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0)]
```

My error:

```
Error in `all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length < 0)]`:
! Can't subset columns with `!...`.
✖ Logical subscript `!...` must be size 1 or 25, not 3879822.
Backtrace:
 1. ...[]
 7. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 8. vctrs:::stop_indicator_size(...)
Error in all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length < :

✖ Logical subscript `!...` must be size 1 or 25, not 3879822.
```

Comment: all_trips2 <- all_trips[(all_trips$start_station_name != "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length < 0)] Have you tried moving the ! to the middle of the equation?

Comment: Seems to me that you forgot to select columns (if you want all, jut add a comma at the end), try the following code: all_trips2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name=="HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0),]

Comment: What is `class(all_trips)`? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you are subsetting a data.frame, you want to use `dataframeanme[rows, cols]`. You seems to be missing the `,` between rows and cols (leave cols blank to select all, but still include the comma)

Comment: Maybe use `all_trips2 <- subset(all_trips, !(start_station_name=="HQ QR" | ride_length<0))`